# deserializing an unknown object type in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

Is possible to deserialize an object that was serialized using binary/xml formatter without knowing or having it's type definition?

PS: By possible I mean if it is possible without having to create a research project and just having a simple prototype that can deserialize into a simplest prototype object that would fit the serialized information.

Comment: Everything is possible, how much effort do you want to put into it.

Comment: Not with xml, it is possible with binary serialization since the data includes the type name.  This usually falls over when the CLR cannot find the proper assembly that contains the type definition.

Comment: Loading the xml into an XDocument instance or using the XmlTextReader will provide you a means to extract data from arbitrary xml.

Comment: @GvS : good point and I like your thinking! Maybe I should rephrase it to is it possible without having to make it to a research project? Or that it has already been and what the example would look like.

Comment: deserialise as object > cast as dynamic. ask if it quacks, cast into duck.